# how can i turn . into ._ for this command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command that will create a link for you to a specific site, but there is a problem, there are stuff that have `.` in them like "Dr. Mike", and if I use `.` in my command it won't work because in the link `.` is replaced by `._`, is there a way so that it will turn `.` into `._` automatically in this command?

```
@client.command()
async def mlwiki(ctx, *args):
    quote = "'"
    print(quote(quote))
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Your Wiki search:", description='**[Results](https://monsterlegends.fandom.com/wiki/{})**'.format('_'.join([arg.capitalize() for arg in args])), color=0x00ff00)
    embedVar.set_footer (text ="Atention!,if you put the terms wrong,the link won't work")
    await ctx.reply(embed=embedVar,mention_author=False)
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? We're having a tough time understanding it.

Comment: Yeah, that was hard to read.  Maybe you could wrap your dot space `._` with backticks ` ...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that'd be easy to [sub with regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import re

string = 'Mr.BlueSky'
newstring = re .sub( r'\.',  r'._',  string )  ##  escape \. for literal dot char

print( newstring )
```

> Mr._BlueSky

Comment: Using regex is a bit overkill, you can simply: `newstring = string.replace(".", "._")`

Comment: Yeah, that's true.  Was just using `re` a minute ago, so it was the first thing that came to mind.